# How do you convey the effect of a poor phone connection?

Tags: phrase-request, politeness

Recently, I was talking on a phone which had a faulty connection, as a result of which I was only able to hear the person's voice in patches. Something like "......I think.........may.......jaguar....study.." (where "..." represents things which he said that I was not able to hear). 
I tried:

> I can hear you only in patches

That sounds awkward. How do I say this to him in a natural way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could say this:

> I'm sorry I can't hear you. You're **breaking up**!

From Macmillan Dictionary:

> **[break up](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/break-up)**
>   5 [intransitive] if the sound on a radio or mobile phone breaks up, you can no longer hear the person who is speaking on it.
>   *I can't hear you, you're breaking up.*

Answer (score 8):

There are various ways of conveying difficulty in hearing a caller:

> You're **breaking up**, it's really difficult to hear you
>   This is a **really bad** connection, could you please call back
>   It's **really difficult** to hear you, could we try again
>   You sound **very spotty**, could you call again

**Breaking up** is a hold over from radio usage days, it can be used for both mobile and landlines.

Usually the caller is asked to **call back** and hopefully a better **connection** is made.
When appropriate, the **caller** may ask if it's possible to recall on a **landline**, or the **callee** may offer a landline to call on.

In **extreme circumstances**

> I can't hear you, can you hear me?

is used and after a few moments the call is automatically ended with reattempts by the caller, or by either side if they know each other.

Comment: +1 In addition: your voice or your phone or my phone keeps *cutting in and out*. Example for [voice cuts out](http://forums.androidcentral.com/moto-x-2013/312820-voice-cutting-out-other-end-call.html).

Comment: @GoDucks If you posted that as an answer, I would upvote it.

Answer (score 4):

Whether the signal is bad due to crosstalk, lost packets, or delayed packets, you can say that the message or sentence is [*garbled*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/garbled):

> **gar·ble**  (gär′bəl)
>
> 1. To mix up or distort to such an extent as to make misleading or incomprehensible: The report garbled all the historical facts.
> 2. To scramble (a signal or message), as by erroneous encoding or faulty transmission.
> 3. …

Note that *garbled* describes the message that was received, not the connection.